# Plesk admin panel C/C++ API examples

Tags: c++, c, plesk

I checked allover the internet to find any examples of ANSI C or C++ Plesk RPC API and I can find none. Any ideas? I just need to write a program that connects to my Plesk panel and enable/disable domain. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

XML-RPC don't dependence on language. 
You need create valid xml and send to server (plesk https server 8443 port) recive her, and parse it. For example, you can to use opensource libs: libxml and curl.

Documentation XML-RPC http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/

Also doc have C# example:
http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/33182.htm